# Calculation of Big O notation complexity for a piece of code

Tags: big-o, pascal

Could you please explain how to calculate Big O complexity of the following segment:

```
i := n;
while i > 1 do
  begin
    for j:= i div 2 + 1 to i do
      begin
        k := 2;
        while n >= k do
          k := k * k
      end;
    i := i div 2
  end;
```

(It's Pascal, but the language isn't really important here.)
The correct answer is `n*log(log(n))`, but I don't know how to get there.

Comment: Really `n*log(log(n))`? I would have  thought `n*log(n)²`.

Comment: It is a part of my exam and teacher marked n*log(log(n)) as the correct solution.

Comment: oh, right, now i see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with the inner loops:

```
    k := 2;
    while n >= k do
      k := k * k
```

This assigns the values 2, 2<sup>2</sup>, 2<sup>4</sup>, 2<sup>8</sup>, .. to `k` till it reaches `n`. This is O(log(log(n)), because, if we call the number of iterations m, it iterates until

```
22m > n   →   log(22m) > log(n)   →   log(log(22m)) > log(log(n))   →

→   m > log(log(n))   →   m = log(log(n)) + 1
```

Then

```
for j:= i div 2 + 1 to i do
  begin
    //O(log(log(n))
  end;
```

This has i / 2 iterations, so it is O( (i / 2) log(log(n)))

```
i := n;
while i > 1 do
  begin
    // (i / 2) log(log(n))
    i := i div 2
  end;
```

This has O(log(n)) iterations of O( (i / 2) log(log(n))) which is summed to

```
  O( (n/2) log(log(n)) + (n/4) log(log(n)) + (n/8) log(log(n)) + (n/16) log(log(n)) + ... ) =
= O( (1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + 1/16 + ...)  n log(log(n)) ) =
= O( 0.1111111…2 n log(log(n)) ) =
= O( n log(log(n)) )
```

(0.11111…<sub>2</sub> = 1, just like 0.999…<sub>10</sub> = 1, but it does not matter in O() anyways )